#  Chapter 5 of Hartl book  Why does routing requires get() for user.new?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest, routes

Around listing 5.29 of the Hartl rails tutorial (http://ruby.railstutorial.org/) there is a discussion of a routing error that forces you to call the get method on users/new and not just a match method.  This is later rectified by calling to the resources method in the next chapter.

My general question is why don't we have to call get() on the PagesController actions in the following listing.

```
 #5.29
 SampleApp::Application.routes.draw do
    get "users/new"

    match '/signup',  :to => 'users#new'

    match '/contact', :to => 'pages#contact'
    match '/about',   :to => 'pages#about'
    match '/help',    :to => 'pages#help'

    root :to => 'pages#home'
 end
```

Answer (score 1):

The difference is in the types of HTTP requests the routes will match.

By using `get "users/new"` the route will only match HTTP GET requests.

`match "users/new"` would actually match all types of HTTP requests.

You can use `get` instead of `match` for your other routes if you only expect GET requests for them (which appears to be the case).